# Official or Unofficial word-break: break-word

Tags: css

[W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#ref-for-valdef-word-break-break-word-1) includes the `break-word` property value, but *MDN* and [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/word-break/embed/) both state:

> Chrome, Safari and other WebKit/Blink browsers also support the unofficial break-word value which is treated like word-wrap: break-word.

Is it officially supported or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "officially". How could something unofficial be officially supported?

Comment: The W3C page in your link describes itself as a working draft. Older versions of this page don't include the break-word value. Anyway, if you need this functionality, why not just write `word-wrap: break-word`?

Comment: @MrLister - that's what we're using. It's just confusing when the spec, even though the document status is working draft, shows a property and that is also a suggested auto-complete or intellisense in our text editors. That's definitely an editor issue, but it made me wonder if I was missing something as it really isn't clear by looking at the W3C spec (I know...Working Draft). Thanks for the responses!